# Risks with setting up a authentication-less public VPN

Tags: authentication, vpn, ddos, api

I'm in the process of setting up an authentication-less public VPN. To prevent against DoS attacks, I'm going to set up some sort of IP address based rate limiting. The VPN is port-bound, i.e., it will only connect to ports 80 and 443 of other sites.

(1) What sort of attacks could I expect (i) on the VPN (ii) conducted via VPN on other websites?

(2) Are there ways in which I can prevent those attacks?

Comment: @bk2204's answer below pretty much sums up why this is a bad idea.  What is the motivation for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're essentially doing is setting up an unauthenticated public proxy with all of the security problems that come along with that.

First of all, your proxy will likely be of interest to several governments and large corporations, since it can be used to bypass filtering or location restrictions (e.g., for streaming sites).  That may lead to overuse or attacks on it to knock it offline.

More importantly, because anybody can use the VPN, it will be used for pretty much any type of abuse imaginable.  Things like sending spam via webmail, conducting DDoS attacks on other people, harassment, sending threats or SWATting people, exfiltrating data, or any of the variety of other unsavory things people do on the Internet.  Limits on rate and ports don't prevent any of these things from happening, since a single person can do a lot of damage with just a little bit of access to websites.

Besides these being bad for other people, your provider probably won't appreciate the abuse complaints, and you may acquire legal liability in any number of jurisdictions for facilitating these activities.  Since there's no authentication, you won't know who's responsible for this behavior.  Moreover, your IP addresses will probably be blocked pretty quickly, so you'll find that the VPN stops working for a lot of sites.

My strong recommendation is not to do this.  Providing this kind of service is not really a good idea on the Internet today because a small number of bad actors can do a huge amount of damage and if anything goes wrong, everybody will blame you.  Everyone providing abusable Internet services has the responsibility to have a robust system for dealing with abuse, and it doesn't sound like this design is going to provide you the opportunity to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer makes me think this is a bad idea :) Does keeping sufficient logs (e.g., with IP addresses) help in any way?

Comment: It means you can block things more effectively if you want and you can find bad actors, but I would still recommend not doing this because people can change their IPs pretty easily and commit more abuse.  Without access control, it's going to be pretty much whack-a-mole.